# ProgrammingError: ('Expected 0 parameters, supplied 391', 'HY000') with 391 columns using dynamic approach

Tags: pandas, pyodbc

I have a dataframe that contains 391 columns and a number of rows. I am trying to push this to a database via pyodbc and using the following command:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(
f"INSERT INTO db.tble({', '.join(df.columns.tolist())}) VALUES ({('?,' * len(df.columns))[:-1]})",
list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
)
cursor.commit()
```

I would have thought this method would be dynamic for a dataframe of any size yet I get the following error:

ProgrammingError: ('Expected 0 parameters, supplied 391', 'HY000')

I am struggling to understand this as the syntax looks correct, `?` has been used instead of `%s` like other answers. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue is here ({('?,' * len(df.columns))[:-1]}), what do you gain from doing it dynamic? in the end the db table is not dynamic , I would suggest to replace it with value (?,?,?....) or better (%s,%s,%s...) as the number of columns

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote a piece of code, where I wanted to create the insert statement dynamically based on number of columns in the data frame:

here is how the insert query would be passed to the database:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (column1,columns2,column3) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

and again, the number of columns and values '?' would be required to be created dynamically at runtime based upon the number of columns the data frame had

I wrote the below piece to just write a string (of ?,?,?) and concatenate it with the insert query,

here
df is the dataframe,
symbol_counter would hold the number of columns in the dataframe,
sym_string would be the final string i.e. (?,?,?,?...n) based on the number of columns

```
        symbol = ['?']
        sym_string = ''
        symbol_counter = int(df.shape[1])-1
        word = 0
        for word in range(symbol_counter):
            # sym_string += str(symbol)
            symbol.insert(word, "?")
            word+=1
        sym_string = (','.join(symbol))


#and then use this variable and concatenate it with the rest of the query as shown below

query =  Variable_holding_first_partofthequery + " VALUES (" +sym_string+")"
```

I know, it's the big way, but that's how I got it to work. Good Luck!